# Generic Numeric range function in Scala

Tags: scala, types, range

I have two functions in scala that do exactly the same like this:

```
  private def getIntRange(minLimit: Int, maxLimit: Int, step: Int): Something = {
    (minLimit to maxLimit by step)
      .map(_.toString)
      .map(
        //something here
      )
      .toList
  }
```

and

```
  private def getDoubleRange(minLimit: Double,
                                            maxLimit: Double,
                                            step: Double): Something = {
    (minLimit to maxLimit by step)
      .map(_.toString)
      .map(
        //same thing here 
        )
      )
      .toList
  }
```

I would like to merge both into a single function that would take a either ints or doubles and create a range with values of the same that was given, int or double respectively.

Is there any way to achieve this without having two separate functions that take different types?

Thank you!

I see that there is `[T : Numeric]` but I need to cast the type to either double or int defeating the purpose.

Comment: There's `NumericRange` (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/NumericRange.html) but that only works with integral numbers, so no `Double`s.

Comment: How did you make `minLimit to maxLimit by step` compile with `Double`s? Do you have some extra implicit conversion?

Comment: Why do you need to cast when using `Numeric`?

Comment: One of the reasons it compiles may be  `import math.BigDecimal.double2bigDecimal` which converts Double to Decimal which can be treated as `Integral`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest some kind of workaround using implicit conversions to `BigDecimal`:

```
import math.BigDecimal.double2bigDecimal
import scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange
import collection.immutable.Range.BigDecimal.bigDecAsIntegral


def getRangeX[A](minLimit: A,
                          maxLimit: A,
                          step: A)(implicit toDecimal: A => BigDecimal) = {
  NumericRange(toDecimal(minLimit), toDecimal(maxLimit), toDecimal(step)).toList
}

getRangeX(1, 10, 2)
getRangeX(1.0, 10.0, 2.0)
```